# How to use html5 video tag in Xamarin.forms based webview?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, webview

I am using xamarin.forms webview and have implemented video tag in my html5 code to play video.

I test it on IOS and Android. None of both play the video. What I am doing wrong?, I read on some SO set hardware acceleration. Someone please help me how this thing work.

Testing code for playing video

```
<p>testing from 3:49</p> <video width='320' height='240' controls> <source src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' type='video/mp4'> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>

    <p>testing from 3:49</p> <video width='320' height='240' controls> <source src='https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.webm' type='video/mp4'> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
```

Comment: Seems you solved it by yourself as mentioned [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6619). You can write an answer below and mark it as a right answer to help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong in my case is I have isEnable property false in WebView. After set it True, it's working fine.

If you still have some issue, try to enable HardwareAccelerate in Mainfest of Android app.